# When did the first exchange-traded warrants appear?

Tags: history, warrant

Exchange-traded options appeared after the Chicago Board Options Exchange (CBOE) opened in 1973. But what about exchange-traded stock warrants? From what I have surmised from reading, exchange-traded warrants did not exist in the early 20th century. When and where did the first exchange-traded warrants appear?

I tried to look up the history on Wikipedia and Google, but did not find anything specific.

Comment: In his famous article *Rational Theory of Warrant Pricing* (1965) Paul Samuelson mentions "Newconex Holdings Warrant, Toronto exchange" (p 21), "Perpetual Tricontinental Warrants" (p 14), "a warrant to buy Kelly Douglas stock at 4.75 per share until November 1965" and "perpetual warrant to buy Allegheny Corporation at 3.75 per share" (p 18). Presumably these are not the first, however.

Comment: According to this NYT article Tricontinental Warrants traded during the Great Depression (!) https://www.nytimes.com/1983/01/12/business/market-place-the-nature-of-warrants.html